# Cairo Library: produce a png file with white background

Tags: c, png, cairo

I searched in INTERNET related to the subject but I found only people that want to save png file with the background transparent.

I report belove the source code that at the moment I use and produces png with background transparent:

```
cairo_surface_t *surface; // Declarations
cairo_t *cr;

// Creations of the surface
surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_ARGB32,3508,2480);

// Contest
cr = cairo_create(surface);

// Moving the plot to center in the page
cairo_translate(cr, 200,200);

// Scaling the plot
cairo_scale(cr,1.8,1.8);

// Make all the necessary actions to produce the plot 
do_drawing(cr);

// write the plot on the file png
cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "image.png");

// End
cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
cairo_destroy(cr);
```

I used also the surface  CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24 but I obtain a black rectangle like plot.

Please could you help me?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cairo_surface_t *surface; // Declarations
cairo_t *cr;

// Creations of the surface
// XXX: Changed to format RGB24; if you don't need transparency, well.
surface = cairo_image_surface_create(CAIRO_FORMAT_RGB24,3508,2480);

// Contest
cr = cairo_create(surface);

// Draw background XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
cairo_save(cr);
cairo_set_source_rgb(cr, 1, 1, 1);
cairo_paint(cr);
cairo_restore(cr);

// Moving the plot to center in the page
cairo_translate(cr, 200,200);

// Scaling the plot
cairo_scale(cr,1.8,1.8);

// Make all the necessary actions to produce the plot 
do_drawing(cr);

// write the plot on the file png
cairo_surface_write_to_png(surface, "image.png");

// End
cairo_surface_destroy(surface);
cairo_destroy(cr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to draw with an opaque background, take a look at the cairo_set_source_rgb function.